# Java | Binary string to byte

Tags: java, binary, byte

I want to convert a string that consists of 8 binary numbers to a byte.
I have tried this method:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(s, 2);
```

Which works fine if the string is "00000000", but doesn't work if it is "11111111".

I suspect is has something to do with the Radix but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `Integer.parseInt` with a radix of `2` like this `Integer.parseInt("11111111", 2)`
2. Then if you really want it as a `byte` simply cast the integer to a `byte` like this (`byte) intValue`

So the complete code is:

```
System.out.println((byte) Integer.parseInt("11111111", 2));
```

**Output:**

```
-1
```

**NB:** Why `-1`? because `byte` is a signed integer of 8 bits going from `-128` to `127` so here instead of having `255` you get `-1`.